# A curious crash in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have an app that presents a "Show Route" button (between present location, and another location previously fixed). Ok, if the user taps the show route button, the map opens, and makes the zoom, and everything goes ok. BUT, if the user tabs "back" button before the zoom movement is completed, then the app crashes.

How could I avoid the user to press the back button? Is there any way to hide it to the user?

Thank you.

PD: This is the crash:

> -[RutaViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10227c30

Then, the app simply freezes, not showing an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` nor `SIGABRT` signal...

Comment: enable zombie objects and run.

Comment: Yeah, ive read it in others questions, but I don't know how to enable it on XCode 4.3.3.

Comment: Click over your project scheme name (top right).....Select run from left pane and select Diagnostics from right pane. Check "Enable Zombie objects"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the crash, try setting your mapView's delegate to nil in your view controller's `viewWillDisappear` method.

Comment: Yes, don't stop the user from doing things but rather fix your things instead!

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps set the button as being disabled when your map begins to zoom?

e.g:

```
-(void)zoomMap
{
   ...

   // set button as disable so user can't press it
   myButton.enabled = NO;

   // now start zooming
   [myMapView setRegion...];
}
```

Comment: Is the back button on the Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the back button before when zooming. And show it when the zooming is complete.

```
backButton.hidden = YES;
```